# java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/pig/deidentifiedDir/

Tags: apache-pig, laminas-api-tools

When I try store data using pig command

```
STORE D into '/deidentifiedDir';
```

Getting this error

```
2015-05-06 20:17:14,587 [Thread-96] WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0009 

java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/pig/deidentifiedDir/_temporary/_attempt_local_0009_m_000000_0

    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:484)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigTextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(PigTextOutputFormat.java:98)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(PigOutputFormat.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
```

Comment: does the user that run the pig can create folder in the root path ?

Comment: no i can't create. how can i create it help me please.

Comment: `You don't have permission to perform the operation. Error from the server: /pig (Permission denied)
2015-05-07 09:47:51,785 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. /pig (Permission denied)`